# Confusion Matrix - Not changing with predictive models (Sklearn)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I have 3 predictive models and I am evaluating there performance with a confusion matrix. 
I am getting the same results for the confusion matrix for each of the 3 models.
I expect that the different models would perform differently and produce different confusion matrices. I am new to predictive modelling, so I suspect I am making a  "Rooky mistake" . The full script I am using  is sitting in a Jupyter notebook  on GiThub [here](https://github.com/AnalyticsInAction/Confusion_Matrix/blob/master/Titanic%20model%20comparison.ipynb)

A screenshot of the code for the 3 models is below

Can some one point out what is going wrong?
Cheers
Mike

[image]

Comment: Try [grid-search](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_grid_search_digits.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-grid-search-digits-py) for tuning the hyperparameters.

Comment: Little remark, you should fit on train, but predict on test, that's where you get meaningful data. Also have you check if all the prediction from all your different model have exactly the same value ?

Comment: @Tbaki Yes, strangely enough, the row value predictions for all 3 of the models are identical. As per Mohammed Kashif suggestion I will split the data using the train_test_split approach to get  more meaningful data, and rerun the predictions.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned: make predictions on the test data. But keep in mind that your targets are skewed! So use StratifiedKFolds or something like this.

Also I guess that your data is a bit corrupted. While all models show the same result it may be a big mistake underneath.

Few questions/advises:
1. Did you scale your data?
2. Did you use one-hot-encoding?
2. Use don't Decision Trees but Forests/XGBoost. Easy to overfit with DT.
3. Don't use >2 hidden layers in NN because it's easy to overfit too. Use 2 firstly. And your architecture (30, 30, 30) with 2 target classes seems weird.
4. And if you wish to use >2 hidden layers - go to Keras or TF. You'll find there many features that can help you to not overfit.

Answer (score -1):

That is simply because you are using the same Training data to make predictions. Since your models are already trained on the same  data that you are making the predictions on, they will return the same results (and ultimately the same confusion matrix). You need to split your dataset into training and test sets. Then train your classifier on training set and make predictions on test set.

You can use [train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) in Sklearn to split your dataset into training or test set.